# where to put -Xms java options

Tags: java, python

I have JavaOutOfMemory error.
I was told to change the -Xms option.
could you please give me detailed steps regarding where to introduce those changes?
I am only using python if it helps.
Thank you

Comment: You need to add more context. Maybe a snippet of code. Explain what you are trying to do, otherwise no one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the program from command line, you can provide the value in command line like java -Xms24m  or if you are using editor you can specifyin VM argument section. like -Xms24m